# Cannot call intent inside retrofit success callback function

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, retrofit

I am new to android and retrofit. When I click login, if the callback returns "successful login" message then I should be redirected to the home page, but it seems that I am not allowed to call intent inside the callback function.

```
public void loginUser() {
    //Here we will handle the http request to insert user to mysql db
    //Creating a RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    LoginAPI api = adapter.create(LoginAPI.class);

    api.loginUser(

            //Passing the values by getting it from editTexts
            editTextUsername.getText().toString(),
            editTextPassword.getText().toString(),

            //Creating an anonymous callback
            new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Response result, Response response) {
                    //On success we will read the server's output using bufferedreader
                    //Creating a bufferedreader object
                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                    //An string to store output from the server
                    String output = "";

                    try {
                        //Initializing buffered reader
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

                        //Reading the output in the string
                        output = reader.readLine();

                        if(output == "Successful login") {
                            Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        //Log.d(TAG, output);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Displaying the output as a toast
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    /*SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
                    editor.putString("callback", output);
                    editor.commit();*/

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //If any error occured displaying the error as toast
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

    );
}
```

Comment: where is this code located? is it inside of an activity or in a separate class?

Comment: It is inside of the login activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong this-pointer.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
```

You should use the this-pointer of your activity, not the one of your anonymous inner class. E.g. If your activity is named Login, you should build your intent in this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need 7 minutes before I can accept an answer.

Comment: @Christopher - its not working even though is used as - intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainListActivity.class);
//                            startActivity(intent);

Comment: "Is not working" is no valid error description. Please explain your problem in detail with the corresponding error message and the relevant code snippets.